# Why I can not get the json content with ajax when page is loading

Tags: html, json, ajax

In my project, i have a page.

I want to get the content from a json file, and make them insert into this page.

The code of this page is like:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pagination.css" >
<script src="jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.pagination.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'get_subnet_resource.json',
        dataType:'json',
        type:'POST',
        data:{},
        success:function(data) 
        {
          //$('#test').html(data);
          /*$('.M-box').pagination({  
           pageCount:50,  
           jump:true,  
           coping:true,  
           homePage:'first',  
           endPage:'last',  
           prevContent:'pre',  
           nextContent:'next',
           callback:function(api) {
            $.ajax({
              dataType:'json',
              type:"POST",
              url:"get_subnet_resource.json",
              data:{page:api.getCurrent()},
              success:function(data) 
              {
                $('#test').html(data);
              }
            });
            */
            alert(data);
        }
        }); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <div class="M-box"></div>  
</body>

 </html>
```

The content of get_subnet_resource.json is like:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
        "img":"img/dingwei.png",
        "manager": "107"

    }, {
        "img": "img/dingwei.png",
        "manager": "108"

    },
    {
        "img": "img/dingwei.png",
        "manager": "109"

    },
    {
        "img": "img/dingwei.png",
        "manager": "110"

    },  
    {
        "img": "img/dingwei.png",
        "manager": "111"      
    }  
  ]
}
```

But when I open this page in Google Chrome, I find it is blank.

I have got nothing. I don't know why

Maybe I forgot somthing.

Comment: open console and check your request status in network tab.

Comment: @Ahmed Sunny, in the console, i have got this message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Not Allowed)

Comment: so the error tells that you json file does not have permissions, try changing permission , read permission especially

Comment: chmod 666 get_subnet_resource.json, after change, i have got another msg:jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2 POST http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/resource/get_subnet_resource.json 405 (Not Allowed)

Comment: I use get replace post, I find it is OK. But I don't know why

Comment: i think it needs execution rights, try giving exe rights

Comment: I give 777 to  get_subnet_resource.json. but it failed again. I think it is not relate to the right.

Comment: are you running locally or on server? i tried the same code it works for me, rights = 0644.

Comment: on linux server.

Comment: then the problem could be, that your file has different user not root  because you cant access every users files, this happened to me when i upload a file directly then user of the file is me and not root or main